# SQL that returns the total products quantity for orders with a status of delivered (different two tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart, product-quantity

I want to get the total products quantity for orders with a status of delivered. How can I write it as a single sql query?

table_1:

| id | order_id | product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100001 | 123456780 | 3 |
| 2 | 100002 | 123456781 | 1 |
| 3 | 100002 | 123456782 | 5 |
| 4 | 100003 | 123456783 | 2 |

table_2:

| id | order_id | order_status | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100001 | preparing | 2023-01-26 |
| 2 | 100001 | prepared | 2023-01-26 |
| 3 | 100001 | delivered | 2023-01-26 |
| 4 | 100002 | preparing | 2023-01-26 |
| 5 | 100002 | prepared | 2023-01-26 |
| 6 | 100002 | delivered | 2023-01-26 |
| 7 | 100003 | preparing | 2023-01-26 |
| 8 | 100004 | preparing | 2023-01-26 |
| 9 | 100001 | returned | 2023-01-27 |

The sql query below didn't work as expected. Because it doesn't look at the latest status of the order:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.quantity) AS total
  FROM table_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
 WHERE t2.order_status = 'delivered'
```

Result: 9 (3+1+5) This result is not correct. Because the last status of the order number 100001 was Returned, it should not have added the number 3 to the total.
Correct result should be 6 (1+5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your query:

- You're not taking the latest record for each order_id. You can do such thing using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function, that assigns a ranking to each record of order_id ordered by order_date descendently (last order_date for each order_id has rownum = 1). Then you can filter on the rownum = 1.
- You're using a `LEFT JOIN`, but you want only rows that can be found in "*table_2*" and that strictly satisfy the conditions. You should rather use the `INNER JOIN`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id 
                                ORDER     BY order_date DESC, id DESC) AS rn
    FROM table_2
)
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM      table_1 t1
INNER JOIN cte     t2
        ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
       AND t2.order_status = 'delivered'
       AND t2.rn = 1
```

---

If you can't use common table expressions for some reason, an equivalent way of dealing with it is turning the cte into a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) 
FROM       table_1 t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id 
                                        ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC) AS rn 
            FROM table_2) t2 
        ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id 
       AND t2.order_status = 'delivered' 
       AND t2.rn = 1
```

Output:

| SUM(quantity) |
| --- |
| 6 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rFVrHEbKUo7a8YYVeuKmZs/0).

Comment: WITH command gave an error for me. I worked your SQL like that: 

SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM table_1 t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC) AS rn FROM table_2) t2 ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id AND t2.order_status = 'delivered' AND t2.rn = 1

Comment: Can you add this sql into your answer?

Comment: Just updated accordingly.